Background package relying on obsolete everypage package
If we try to apply this answer in 2024, we get:

Package everypage Warning: Functionality similar to this package has recently
(everypage)                been implemented in LaTeX. This package is now in
(everypage)                legacy status.
(everypage)                Please, don't use it in new documents and packages.

The problem clearly is that everypage is being loaded by the background package. So what should I do instead until the background package gets updated?

For an overview see, e.g. my answer here. The answer can easily be adapted to print colored bars using either \color and \rule or TikZ instead of printing images. And it is also easy to reduce the number of "images" or to change the position.

you could ignore the warning, or just use the shipout hooks to add your background, no package is needed.

You might also need the transparent package.

You could simply ignore the warning, it is not an error just warning of use of an old package.
Especially if you have made large use of the specific options and configuration of the background package that may be the best thing to do, and if the package gets updated the warnings will go with no change to the document.
However, no package is needed to add items to the background in current releases, so if you are not tied to the specific background package interface you could do something like

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \put(100,-150){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}%
  \put(3in,-5in){\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}}%
  \put(8cm,-15cm){\hbox{\Huge\sffamily Some Background text}}%
}

\begin{document}

\def\x{Some text some text \stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi} more text}
\def\xx{\x\ \x\ \x \x. Filler text in the forground \x. \x. \x.
  \x. \x. \x. \x. \x. \x.}

\xx\par\xx\par\xx\par\xx\par\xx\par\xx\par\xx\par\xx\par
\end{document}


And what would be the cleanest way to put a solid colour in the background?

@Gaussler well you could just use \textcolor{red}{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}} \put at a suitable place, or as I say you could use background (which uses tikz) with \AddEverypageHook replaced by  \AddToHook{shipout/background} I'm not sure The author is still active but you could ask, or make a locally updated copy.

@Gaussler or of course not use a hook at all and use \pagecolor{blue}

Well, I only want the colour on a part of each page, so hook it is.

What if I only wanted to add something to the background of a specific page?

@Gaussler There is \AddToHookNext which only adds to the hook once the next time it is used. Place this before the next page, to add something to the background of that page.

@JasperHabicht Thanks, works perfectly!
